# How to launch my app on vercel even though it is successful in local create react app

Tags: reactjs, vercel, newsapi

Fail to launch host on vercel, even though it was successful in local create react app

There are too many codes! Here is the link to the github repo, feel free to clone it to give it a look

https://github.com/dunyanong/Kopitiam-News

Errors in my console

```
Error handling response: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '1')x

main.78df1ac9.js:2          GET https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=in&apiKey=a1ec1c47dff64cc1a11743631374ff5e&page=1 426


react_devtools_backend.js:4026 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

main.78df1ac9.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')


Uncaught (in promise) Error: A listener indicated an asynchronous response by returning true, but the message channel closed before a response was received
```

Comment: There is no code so we can only guess what the problem is. Please add your code

Comment: @Codebling, question has been edited, I would definitely appreciate your help

Comment: There are multiple errors and I unfortunately have a job and can't take the time to debug your entire code. One of the errors says `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
`. Searching for `map` in your code shows only one result, [here](https://github.com/dunyanong/Kopitiam-News/blob/1f92cb620c6f4e3cd2f298bf56f36d2d46e1fc87/src/components/News.js#L56). So it seems like `articles` is null or undefined

Comment: That's about all I can help with. You should separate each error into its own question and post only relevant code in that question. Turn on source maps or find a way to map the line numbers from the bundled files (`main.78df1ac9.js:2`) to the real files (`src/components/News.js:56`). This will make people more likely to answer your question. Good luck